Thermally Assisted Alpha Particle Decay
I am attempting to solve the following exercise from Condensed Matter Field Theory by Altland and Simons:
Consider a heavy nucleus having a finite rate of $\alpha$-decay. The nuclear forces are short range so that the rate of $\alpha$-emission is controlled by the tunneling of $\alpha$-particles under a Coulomb barrier. Taking the effective potential to be spherically symmetric, with a deep well of radius $r_0$ beyond which it decays as
$$ U(r) = \frac{2(Z - 1)e^2}{r}, $$
where $Z$ is the nuclear charge, find the temperature $T$ of the nuclei above which $\alpha$-decay is thermally assisted if the energy of the emitted particles is $E_0$. Estimate the mean energy of the $\alpha$ particles as a function of $T$.
I have the following questions about the problem:

What is $E_0$? Is it the energy of a metastable state, modeled as a resonant scattering state?
What does thermally assisted mean, i.e., what is the mathematical criterion for a process to be thermally assisted at a temperature $T$?

My attempt at a solution is the following:
Assume $V(r) = V_0 < U(r_0)$ for $r < r_0$. Model the particles inside the well as being three-dimensional free particles with velocities distributed according to the canonical ensemble, so they have average energies $\frac{3}{2} T$ (in units where $k_b = 1$). We say that the process is thermally assisted if $U(r_0) - E_0 \leq \langle E \rangle$, where $\langle E \rangle$ is the average energy of the particles in the canonical ensemble, so we have the criterion $T \geq \frac{2}{3}(U(r_0) - E_0)$. Then, assuming the energy is modeled according to the canonical ensemble, I guess we would have $\langle E\rangle = E_0 + \frac{3}{2} T$ (but, if this is right, I'm not really sure how to justify it).

2d edition? I can't find the exercise you are referring to.

@LPZ It's in the third chapter of the third edition right after they do some example tunneling calculations with instantons.
